# Could someone please point me what's wrong with the php statement?

Tags: php

```
function organisation_before_email_field() {
   $mepr_options = MeprOptions::fetch();
   if ( $mepr_options->custom_fields = array( (object)array('field_key' => 'mepr_organisation') ) ) { ?>
        <div class="mp-form-row mepr_custom_field mepr_<?php echo $line->field_key; ?>">
            <?php if($line->field_key = 'mepr_organisation') : ?>
                <div class="mp-form-label">
                  <label for="<?php echo $line->field_key . $unique_suffix; ?>"><?php printf( '%1$s:%2$s', _x(stripslashes($line->field_name), 'ui', 'memberpress'), $required ); ?></label>
                  <span class="cc-error"><?php ($line->required) /*here for email custom fields that are not required*/ ? printf(_x('%s is Required', 'ui', 'memberpress'), stripslashes($line->field_name)) : printf(_x('%s is not valid', 'ui', 'memberpress'), stripslashes($line->field_name)); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php echo MeprUsersHelper::render_custom_field($line,$value,array(),$unique_suffix); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    }
<? } ?> <? }

add_action ('mepr-after-email-field','organisation_before_email_field');
```

Comment: The only thing wrong here is the fact that we have no idea what's telling you it's wrong. Do you have any errors ?

Comment: The closing of if statement might be something PHP is throwing errors.

Comment: The closing of if 
<? } ?> <? }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have syntax (opening closing php tags) error.
instead of 
`<? } ?> <? }` 
use

```
<?php } 
} 
add_action ('mepr-after-email-field','organisation_before_email_field'); 
?>
```